# Sockets on a private network

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, embedded

I'm developing a two part product. One part is a C# app on a single board computer running Windows Embedded Standard. The other piece is an embedded device running an RTOS with a TCP/IP stack. The two devices need to communicate via an Ethernet cable. It's a point to point connection. Nothing is connected to any outside network.

I'm a bit of a network programming novice, so I'm looking for best practices. I'm making the assumption that TCP sockets is the most straightforward approach. I figured I'd get some advice before writing any code and getting lost.

The one thing that is guaranteed is that the embedded device will maintain a static IP address of 169.254.1.1. That's about all I know. So what do I need to know to get these guys connected? I know there are issues with subnets... but that's where my knowledge is falling short. Which should be the client, which is the server, port numbers etc.

Little more info per request: The two ends are going to be exchanging a pretty simple binary protocol. That part is already defined and it working over an RS-232 link. But the RS-232 port is going away. I want to use TCP to basically carry this information, plus give me all the the good stuff like retries and error checking. Either end of the system can initiate a transfer.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: We're going to need a bit more details on what you're doing to tell you who is the 'client' and who is the 'server'. Or if you need peer to peer. Or what.

Comment: The embedded device, with its fixed IP address, should be the server.  Pick an 'unused' port number, (whatever that is), 8086 say, for the device to listen on. The SBC can be the client  - connect to 169.254.1.1:8086  'Either end of the system can initiate a transfer.' - OK, you need to keep the connection open permanently and use a protocol that allows either side to initiate the transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into some introduction to socket programming, like http://beej.us/guide/bgnet.

The windows node will have to configure a network interface in the same
subnet as the rtos device and choose a (different) ip address from that
subnet.

Which device is the server and waits for a connection depends on your
application, maybe also on the boot order of the two nodes. For example,
if the RTOS device has booted first, it might wait for a TCP connection 
until the other side is ready.

Of course, you'll need some protocol inside the tcp stream. Possibly UDP
might also be an option, if you don't need the features TCP provides. This
might also reduce the memory footprint on the RTOS side.

If the two sides can reboot (or crash :-) indenpedently from each other without
some hardware watchdog taking note, be sure that the other side recognizes the
reboot (e.g. with the tcp keepalive feature), so that you can reestablish the
connection.

With TCP you'll get the reliable connection, but depending on you application,
you might discover that the Nagle algorithm keeps your message latency higher
than what the RS232 setup had. Use the NO_DELAY option on the socket to avoid
this.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you very much against doing TCP yourself. It is nice but has many hard-to-discover pitfalls for machine-to-machine interface (e.g. naggling, KA configuration, testing the packetizing state machine).

We are in 2012. You can use ZeroMQ and similar [feel free to edit with more and good IP messaging libraries].

Comment: zeromq shouldn't be a problem on the windows embedded side, but on the RTOS I'm not so sure if the effort of porting such a library would be worth the benefits (http://lists.zeromq.org/pipermail/zeromq-dev/2011-November/014548.html).